# How to target parent component from child

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have two components. A `Child` and a `Parent`. I want to display the child when the parent is hovered over

So essentially, I'm trying to do this:

```
const Child = styled.div`
  display: none;

  ${Parent}:hover & {
    display: block;
  }
`

const Parent = styled(({ className, ...props }) => {
  // Some logic

  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <ItemName />
    </div>
  );
})`
 display: flex;
 ...
`;
```

However, I can't refer to the parent since the parent is declared after the child

I could create a styled div to wrap this child in the parent and target that instead. i.e:

```
<Parent>
  <WrapperToTarget>
    <Child />
  </WrapperToTarget>
</Parent>
```

but seems like a bad workaround.

For now, I've manually added a class to the parent and targeted that instead

```
const Child = styled.div`
  display: none;

  parent:hover & {
    display: block;
  }
`

const Parent = styled(({ className, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <div className={classNames(className, 'parent')}>
      <ItemName />
    </div>
  );
})``
```

but not sure if there's a "pure styled component" way to do this

Whats a good approach to this?

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for your use-case?

```
const HoverDisplayChildrenDiv = styled.div`
  & > * {
    display: none;
  }

  :hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    & > * {
      display: block;
    }
  }
`;
```

Usage:

```
const Child = props => <div>Child</div>;

const Parent = styled(HoverDisplayChildrenDiv)`
  background-color: lightgray;
`;
```

[image: Edit exciting-lalande-pmuul]